# In emacs incremental search, how can I cut the highlighted selection to the kill ring?

Tags: search, emacs, selection, copy-paste

In Emacs's incremental search (`C-s`), `C-w` will append the next word to the search. I can then copy the highlighted text to the kill ring using `M-w`, but because `C-w` is in incremental-search mode and appending the next word, I can't use it to cut the highlighted selection to the kill ring.

Is there a quick way to exit incremental search but keep the search text highlighted at point so I can use `C-w` to kill it? Or an incremental search command I missed that will do this?

--- Update: From the comments I think my question wasn't totally clear. I'd like to be able to cut from the buffer any particular instance of the search string while doing an incremental search. So, C-s, C-w C-w to append words, C-s C-s to find an occurrence, then cut that instance. Or, just C-s C-w C-w, and then cut, to use isearch as a shortcut to highlight the text at point that I'd like to cut. Regarding the comments about M-e, that doesn't cut the text from the buffer, which was the heart of my original question - how to cut as opposed to copy.

Comment: Is this for regexp or ordinary search?

Comment: I meant for ordinary incremental search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```el
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-s M-w") #'my-isearch-copy-match)
(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "M-s C-w") #'my-isearch-kill-match)

(defun my-isearch-copy-match ()
  "Copy the currently-matched text to the kill ring."
  (interactive)
  (kill-new (buffer-substring (min (point) isearch-other-end)
                              (max (point) isearch-other-end))))

(defun my-isearch-kill-match ()
  "Kill the currently-matched text."
  (interactive)
  (kill-region (min (point) isearch-other-end)
               (max (point) isearch-other-end)))
```

If you want these commands to automatically drop out of the isearch, then add a call to `(isearch-exit)` at the end of each function.

The <kbd>M-s</kbd><kbd>M-w</kbd> key binding shadows `eww-search-words` in the global keymap, but it just seems like the *correct* binding for this command (and it's easy enough to drop out of isearch normally with <kbd>RET</kbd> if you ever want to call the eww command whilst isearching).

Answer (score 0):

Use library [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus) ([**`isearch+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el)), customize option **`isearchp-set-region-flag`** to ON (non-`nil`). When ON the search match is selected as the region when you exit Isearch. Then you can use `C-w` to kill it to the `kill-ring`.

You can use **`M-s M-SPC`** anytime during Isearch to toggle `isearchp-set-region-flag` ON/OFF.

> **`isearchp-set-region-flag`** is a variable defined in [**`isearch+.el`**](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/isearch%2b.el).
>
> Its value is `nil`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means set region around search target.
>
> This is used only for Transient Mark mode.
> You can toggle this using **`M-s M-SPC`** during Isearch.
>
> You can customize this variable.

---

If you just want to *copy* the *search string* (not any particular *match* for it in the searched buffer) to the `kill-ring`, you can do that with **`M-w`** anytime during Isearch.

Without Isearch+ you can use `M-e` to edit the search string, and copy it to the `kill-ring` in that edit buffer.

Comment: Thanks - this also looks like a great solution. Since the original question was about emacs' built-in incremental search (at least, that's what I meant), I chose that as the solution. But I will also check out ISearch+.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `M-e` to edit the search string (which, modulo flexible matches for whitespace or accents or so, is the same as the matched string) and then kill that (*e.g.*, with `C-a C-k` for single lines).

Comment: FWIW, I think this answer just repeats what my answer said: *"you can use M-e to edit the search string, and copy it to the kill-ring in that edit buffer."*. (There's no sense killing versus copying the search string from `M-e`.)

Comment: @Drew: You’re right—I didn’t read the end to see that it switched away from Isearch+.  I’ll delete mine if you like, but others might not find the `M-e` approach in your answer any better than I did.

Comment: I think it would be good to delete it. Thx. In any case, it doesn't really answer the question, as the search string is something quite different from an occurrence which it matches, which is what the OP is about, your ("modulo...") parenthetical remark notwithstanding (consider regexp search, for example).

Comment: @Drew: That’s why I explicitly asked whether it was a regular expression search before answering (which is why it appeared after yours, which suggested the same thing before that clarification appeared).